# convert ArrayList<ArrayList<double[]>> to double [][] in java

Tags: java

Please help me in understanding, looking for a solution. I have

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<double[]>> nwvals = new ArrayList<ArrayList<double[]>>();
```

And I have `double[][]` value.

I am setting nwvals to value

```
setValue(nwvals);
```

How to convert `ArrayList<ArrayList<double[]>>` to `double[][]`?

Comment: That ArrayList would be converted to `double[][][]`, if at all required.

Comment: As @RohitJain pointed out, that would be a 3D array. Did you mean just `ArrayList<double[]>` ?

Comment: Please provide more context, explain better what the error or need is, and kindly tell us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Converting

```
ArrayList<double[]> nwvals;
```

to a `double[][]` will work like this:

```
double[][] result = nwvals.toArray(new double[0][]);
```

Example:

```
import java.util.*;
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<double[]> nwvals = new ArrayList<>();
        nwvals.add(new double[] { 1.,2.});
        double[][] result = nwvals.toArray(new double[0][]);
        System.out.println(result[0][0]);
        System.out.println(result[0][1]);
    }
}
```

Converting `ArrayList<ArrayList<double[]>>` to a `double[][][]` will definitely require a loop, and so would converting `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>` to a `double[][]`.

There it depends on wich Java version you use - you can do a lot with streams here.